# Is a mysql query always executed even if it is in a php if?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Just wondering. Say I have this in a php page

```
<?php
if x {
$query = mysql_query(etc)
}else{
$query2 = mysql_query(etc)
}
?>
```

Lets say X = true then $query is executed, but is $query2 completely ignored? (so also not executed in the background?)

Thanks

Comment: what is "background" you are talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

anything within the "else" bracket will not be executed unless the condition is false. Not even "in the background".  PHP will completely ignore it as if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Lines that are bypassed in a control structure are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

you know, that's the point of the *conditional* statement.
If it was executing both statements, there would be no sense in having it at all.